# QLPreviewController does not show the icon correctly for picture file

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I am testing Apple's DocInteraction sample app.  On the simulator it works fine.  But on the iPad, the icon for the picture does not show up.    Any suggestion how to remedy this?

[image]

Comment: the same problem here. Look like QuickLook Framework in iPad and iPhone have different set of File Icons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating my device to iOS 5.1, it worked correctly now.